# WordPress/WooCommerce - Custom Query to get "Ending Soon" Products

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

**Scenario:** I am using WordPress + Woocommerce on my site. On my product category page, I want to add another search filter other than the defaults offered by WC. This filter would show the products that are going to end soon.
My approach to this part is I set the expiration date of the product and then write a query that would sort the products by remaining number of days from the expiration date.

I have done most of the part (thanks to Google). Here is the query what I have written so far.

```
    <?php 
            $event_query = new WP_Query(
            array( 
              'post_type'   => 'product',        
              'meta_key'    => '_crowdfundingtodatepicker', 
              'order_by'        => 'meta_value',
              'order'       => 'asc',      
              'meta_query'  => array(
                 array(         
                  'key'     => '_crowdfundingtodatepicker', 
                  'value'   => date("m/d/Y"), 
                  'compare' => '>',  
                  'type'    => 'CHAR'
                ) 
               ) 
              ) 
            );

     ?>
```

The format of **_crowdfundingtodatepicker** in the database is **"m/d/Y"** i.e **"10/30/2015"**.

I am stuck at the compare part. The product going to end soonest would be the first one on the display and so on. i.e.
The product with expiration date of "11/01/2015" would be shown first than the product with expiration date of "12/01/2015". Any help?

Comment: hey, did you get anything for this?

Comment: @MaulikVora I' solved that with a workaround. If you can elaborate your situation or open a question and send me a link then I might be able to help.